# number of lines returned from TapiManager

Tags: tapi, avaya

I`m working with **Avaya IP Office TAPI2** service provider.

I have a question regarding how the lines available to work with are obtained.

If i run a test piece of code from my **dev PC**, to initiate a **TapiManager** object and work with the collection of **TapiLine** objects exposed by **TapiManager.Lines**

the number of lines returned is more than the number of lines which are exposed on a server running the same test windows forms app. Both machines, i.e. my dev PC and the server have the same **TAPI2** provider installed and both are connecting to the same switch **IP** address under Third Party

**dev PC** returns something like 460 lines, server has 30 less at 430, and entries which are missing i`m assured by our tech guys that the extentions/lines are configured the same as ones which do appear in the available list.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Avaya TSP exposes two types of IP Office objects:

1. Users (extensions and TAPI WAV users)
2. Hunt Groups

The devices listed as available lines, when configured in third-party mode, is dependent on whether the *TAPI WAV* and *ACD queues* checkboxes are selected (see Control Panel|Phone and Modem Options).

I would verify that both servers have their TAPI options configured identically in the TSP settings in Phone and Modem Options, e.g. you may not have ACD Queues checked on the server.

FYI - you can also use the *Ex Directory* attribute (see *Users* in the IP Office Manager) to control which extensions are visible via TAPI but that will have the same affect on both servers.

The only other thing I think of is whether the machines were restarted after new extensions were added to the IP Office? The TSP will only download a list of lines at startup so extensions added after the TSP is loaded by Windows will not be aware of the new extensions.

If you can enable the TSP logging for the Avaya TSP and include I can review the difference between the two machines.